# Where does the concept of a genie granting three wishes come from?

Tags: cinema-history

Perhaps the most culturally well-known genie today is the one from Disney's *Aladdin*, who granted Aladdin "three wishes, three.  Uno, dos, tres, no substitutions, exchanges, or refunds, and *ixnay* on the wishing for more wishes."

This is not the way the genie from *The Arabian Nights* worked.  (First off, there were two of them in the story of *Aladdin,* but that's beside the point.)  The Genie of the Lamp had to grant unlimited wishes to Aladdin.  I remember when the Disney movie first came out, thinking, "that's not how the story goes, but 'three wishes' is kind of the standard, so OK."

But now, thinking back, I can't help but wonder.  When did "three wishes" become the standard?  Where does that idea come from?

Comment: do you mean in a cinematic-history sense, or a literature sense?  because I bet it predates film, but I'm unsure.

Comment: Well, you can start from here: http://www.giantglacier.com/the-origin-of-the-genie-in-the-lamp/

Comment: @DForck42 Actually it would really surprise me if it wasn't an invention of either the film or TV industries.  This feels like the sort of change that's commonly done to simplify things for a mass audience.

Comment: I think you should edit the question to something like: "When the concept of a genie granting three wishes was first introduced **in a movie**?"

Comment: The oldest I know really comes from Aladdin's story in _One Thousand and One Nights_. Although it has some differences as he had 2 genies there. One who granted one wish and another who granted three. IIRC...

Comment: @LeonFreire It's been a while since I read it, but I'm pretty sure that neither of the genies put any limit on the number of wishes they would grant.  They were both portrayed as outright slaves, required to do their Master's bidding.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I see. That's why my "IIRC" edit a few seconds later. I gotta re-read it.

Comment: @MasonWheeler There is a good theory [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/3r3ccr/where_does_the_idea_of_a_genie_who_grants_three/), about the Woodcutter from _Panchtantra_.

Comment: If it was an undetermined amount of wishes, there would never be any kind of conundrum or thought in choosing a wish, dramatically-speaking.

Comment: This isn't really a movies & TV question; I'm pretty sure the concept of a genie granting three wishes goes back for hundreds of years before cinema was invented. **I suggest you ask this question on [literature.se] SE instead**, if you really want insight into where the idea came from rather than how it transitioned from written material to the screen. Or [scifi.se] SE, which covers both written and screen material provided it's sci-fi or fantasy (which genies are).

Comment: Just asked: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203836/2531 - answer suggests a source older than the answer here.

Answer (score 4):

The Ridiculous Wishes or The Three Ridiculous Wishes is a French literary fairy tale by Charles Perrault published in 1697 in the volume titled Histoires ou contes du temps passé.

You will find reference from the first "mainstream" Genie and three wishes originated from the 1697 french book. One of the first examples is the Genie freed by Abu, the eponymous character in the 1940 film Thief of Baghdad.

Abu makes one of his three wishes for sausages. This is derived from the work mentioned above. The woman in the 1697 French work asks for a sausage, everything goes downhill from there for the wife and her husband in that work.

Many religions try to claim the first records of Djins or Genies using their religious books. The French work of 1697 is the first documented use of this plot line with a Genie.